# How to substitute spaces with underscore in a dir using ipython?

Tags: python, ipython

Sometimes it is useful to substitute spaces with underscore. On linux machine, this works fine for me:

```
find /tmp/ -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /_/g' "{}" \;
```

On windows, I'd like to do it using ipython. I think many people might have met this problem, how do you  implement it in ipython?

Thank you!

Edit:
My apologize for the misunderstanding. Here is my script:

```
import os

def rm_space():
    for filename in os.listdir("."):
        if filename.find(" ") > 0:
            newfilename = filename.replace(" ", "_")
            os.rename(filename, newfilename)
```

This piece of code does substitute the spaces with underscore; however, there's a problem: How to substitute **recursively**?

I think this is a very common problem, that there might be already an idiomatic way to solve it, (just like the shell script above).

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Answer (score 1):

Code copy from stackoverflow and edit, works on my Mac.

```
import os
import sys

directory = sys.argv[1] # parse through file list in the current directory

for filename in os.listdir(directory): # parse through file list in the current directory

    if filename.find(" ") > 0: # if an space is found

        newfilename = filename.replace(" ","_") # convert underscores to space's

        old_file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename) 
        new_file_path = os.path.join(directory, newfilename)

        os.rename(old_file_path, new_file_path) # rename the file, note that arg[] of os.rename is path_of_file, that explains 2 lines of code above
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to substitute recursively?

Use [OS.walk()](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/python-os-walk/) rather than listdir

Comment: Thank you for your hint and the tutorial link! I got this error: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find' Then how to search for spaces in a file/dir name?
I'm new to programming, and I'm learning from example to example. In my understanding, tuple is immutable, then how to substitute?

Comment: Hi Nick. You'll notice that OS.walk returns a set of 3 values; this is the tuple that error is referring to. In the example linked they map it to "root, dirs, files", in `for root, dirs, files in OS.walk`). You probably want to examine what the `files` component is returning you.

Comment: Thanks RJFalconer! I tried in this way:      ` import os

def rm_space():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
        for fn in files:
            if fn.find(" ") > 0:
                n  =  files.replace(" ", "_")
                if n != fn :
                    os.rename(fn, n)
                else:
                    os.rename(fn, "_"+n) `
but failed. I know I may learn more on python and its api before I could write effective code; however, I need to get this job done. This is why I kept trying.